# Excel - Filter Numeric Values using "End With"

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My colleague noticed something funny with Excel. If you have numeric values, and you are trying to use a custom filter that "Ends with" `.13`, as shown below

[image]

It filters and removes everything, rather than narrowing to only the `56.13` value.

[image]

Is there a way to accomplish this so it yields the `56.13`? Hopefully without creating extra columns with text/numeric conversion operations?

Comment: Just type in the `.13` in the normal search box in the dropdown.

Comment: Valid. I guess that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually `EndsWith` only applies to Text, but here is a tiny trick:

In **C2** enter:

```
=TEXT(B2,"General")
```

and copy down.

Then apply your filter criteria to column **C**:

[image]

which results in:

[image]

Because its a secret, please don't tell anyone else.

Comment: Your secret is safe with me!